# Rails_admin, adding render configurations slows page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm using `rails_admin` and I wanted to include/exclude field depending on logged in user.

Inside my models code, I have added `rails_admin` method:

```
rails_admin do
  update do
    include_all_fields
    field :password do
    label do
      if bindings[:view]._current_user._type == 'Owner'
        'Password'
      else
        false
      end
    end
    help do
      if bindings[:view]._current_user._type == 'Owner'
        'Length more than 8'
      else
        false
      end
    end
    render do
      if bindings[:view]._current_user._type == 'Owner'
        bindings[:view].render :partial => "rails_admin/main/#{partial}", :locals => {:field => self, :form => bindings[:form] }
      else
        ''
      end
    end
   end
  end
end
```

In update action, `:password` field will be rendered if current logged user has `_type == 'Owner'`value.

This works, but when I try to load page which is connected to this action. It loads **very slowly**.

How to make page load faster? Is there another way to exclude fields conditionally?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? If Rails 3/4, then you may want to consider checking out the [turbolinks gem](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks). Many use it to quickly load pages. Do know, there are some issues with it (as in, javascript may need to be explicitly called in the view upon `page:change`).

Comment: I'm using Rails 4. About explicitly calling javascript, could you describe it?

Comment: Turbolinks works by only reloading parts of the DOM that changes between page loads. It makes the app work similar to a SPA. Sometimes if you have javascript that runs via `$(document).reload` you have to call `$(document).on('page:change`, ())` or something like that. You may also have to call to render javascript explicitly in the view, rather than loading it from app/assets

Comment: Please write as an answer, what to write and where.

Comment: I did not write as an answer because IDK if it will help solve your problem. It is just a suggestion, and better suited for a comment. Also, because I would not know where in your app things need to be rendered explicitly.